# How does one convert spectral radiance from $\mathrm{(W\: cm^{-2} \: sr^{-1} )/ nm}$ to $\mathrm{ (W \:cm^{-2} \: sr^{-1} )/ cm^{-1}}$?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, units, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

How does one convert spectral radiance from $\mathrm{(W\: cm^{-2} \: sr^{-1} )/ nm}$ to $\mathrm{ (W \:cm^{-2} \: sr^{-1} )/ cm^{-1}}$? The first one is the radiance represented by wavelength and second one is represented by wavenumber.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted and closed?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to transform from a spectral radiance in wavelength (which has units commensurable with $\mathrm{W\: cm^{-2} \: nm^{-1} \: sr^{-1}}$) to a spectral radiance in *wavenumber*, which has units commensurable with
$$
\mathrm{\frac{W\: cm^{-2} \: sr^{-1}}{cm^{-1}}}
=
\mathrm{W\: cm^{-2} \: cm \: sr^{-1}}
=
\mathrm{W\: cm^{-1} \: sr^{-1}}
,
$$
then the easiest way is to look at the integral form of the physical power delivered by the source in a given wavelength/wavenumber range. Thus, to convert between the two, let $P_\lambda(\lambda)$ be the wavelength spectral radiance and $P_k(k)$ be the wavenumber spectral radiance, where $k=2\pi/\lambda$. Then the radiance between wavelengths $\lambda_1=2\pi/k_1$ and $\lambda_2=2\pi/k_2$ is given by
\begin{align}
\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} P_\lambda(\lambda) \:\mathrm d\lambda
&=
\int_{2\pi/\lambda_1}^{2\pi/\lambda_2} P_\lambda(2\pi/k) \frac{-2\pi \mathrm dk}{k^2}
=
\int_{k_2}^{k_1} \frac{2\pi  P_\lambda(2\pi/k)}{k^2}\mathrm dk
=
\int_{k_2}^{k_1} P_k(k)\mathrm dk
,
\end{align}
from which you can read off the relationship between the densities as
\begin{align}
P_k(k)
=
\frac{2\pi  }{k^2}P_\lambda(2\pi/k).
\end{align}
With that, then, you can relate the two: if you have a light source that has a wavelength spectral radiance of
$$
P_\lambda(\lambda) = \{P_\lambda(\lambda)\}\:\mathrm{W\: cm^{-2} \: nm^{-1} \: sr^{-1}}
$$
at some given wavelength $\lambda=\{\lambda\}\:\mathrm{nm}$, then it will have a wavenumber spectral radiance of
\begin{align}
P_k(k)
&=
\frac{2\pi}{k^2}P_\lambda(2\pi/k)
\\&=
\frac{\lambda^2}{2\pi}P_\lambda(\lambda)
\\&=
\frac{\{\lambda\}^2\:\mathrm{nm}^2}{2\pi}\{P_\lambda(\lambda)\}\:\mathrm{W\: cm^{-2} \: nm^{-1} \: sr^{-1}}
\\&=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\{\lambda\}^2\{P_\lambda(\lambda)\}\:\mathrm{W\: cm^{-2} \: nm^{+1} \: sr^{-1}}
\\&=
\frac{10^{-7}}{2\pi}\{\lambda\}^2\{P_\lambda(\lambda)\}\:\mathrm{W\: cm^{-2} \: cm^{+1} \: sr^{-1}}
\\&=
\frac{10^{-7}}{2\pi}\{\lambda\}^2\{P_\lambda(\lambda)\}\:\mathrm{W\: cm \: sr^{-1}}
\end{align}
at the wavenumber $k=2\pi/\lambda$.