# How to calculate energy per range of nm

Tags: electromagnetism, luminosity

$K=hc/\mathrm{wavelength}$ is the usual for finding energy for one particular wavelength. But how would one calculate a range of wavelengths incident on a particular sized surface area? Because no source is ever just one wavelength. It's always a range.

For instance, I'd like to calculate what difference in energy ($K$) 100-120 nm range would have as opposed to the same area exposed to 200-240nm. 
How is that disentangled from luminosity? For instance if I were to split white light into a spectrum, expose a redder part of the spectrum onto a surface through a hole of a particular size, then compare that to exposing a slightly different shorter wavelength part of the same spectrum through the same hole onto the same surface. Obviously the second exposure will be slightly shorter wavelength. So should have more incident energy.
How would that be quantified?

Answer (score 1):

Typically we would have some function $I(\lambda)$ that gives the power as a function of wavelength. The meaning of this is that the power of the radiation for wavelengths between $\lambda$ and $\lambda +d\lambda$ is:

$$ P = I(\lambda)\,d\lambda $$

And the power between the wavelengths $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is then obtained simply by integrating our function:

$$ P_{\lambda_1\to\lambda_2} = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} I(\lambda)\,d\lambda $$

The obvious question is how to find the function $(\lambda)$, and the answer is that it depends. You use the example of sunlight, and to a good approximation sunlight has a [black body spectrum described by Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law). In that case the function is:

$$ I(\lambda) = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5} \frac{1}{e^{hc/\lambda kT} - 1} $$

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're looking for is called [spectral irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance#Spectral_irradiance), which is one of the [huge gamut of radiometric units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance#SI_radiometry_units). It does pretty much what you asked for ─ it takes the incident power per unit surface area, and then decomposes it spectrally, so you get $E_{e,\lambda}$ watts per square meter, per nanometer of wavelength incident on your sample.

Thus, if you know the spectral irradiance and you want to calculate the power that passes a surface $S$ in the wavelength interval $\lambda_1\leq \lambda \leq \lambda_2$, then you just integrate it via
$$
P = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} \int_S E_{e,\lambda}\:\mathrm dS\:\mathrm d\lambda.
$$
(A word of warning: spectral quantities come in both per-unit-wavelength and per-unit-frequency / per-unit-[wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) flavours. The two are informationally [equivalent](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/346151/8563) but they do require nontrivial conversion algebra.)

Now, what if you don't know the spectral irradiance of your source, and you want to calculate it? Well, this depends on the light source, but normally it's not something you calculate, it's something you measure, and different light sources will have vastly different spectra. Some spectra are known analytical forms that offer good approximations (e.g. Planck's-law spectra for thermal sources, gaussians for some lasers, and so on), but there's ultimately no substitute for experimental measurements here.

---

Oh, and just to clear up a potential misconception:

> Obviously the second exposure will be slightly shorter wavelength. So should have more incident energy.

There's nothing "obvious" to the fact that a source of shorter wavelength will carry more energy. The wavelength determines the energy of *each individual photon*, and that needs to be multiplied by how many photons are in the beam. You can have red photons at half the photon energy of blue photons, with twice as many photons passing through, giving you identical intensities. Or, in other words, the frequency and photon energy of the light is entirely decoupled from its intensity.

Comment: @N.Tomson No, that is entirely incorrect. The blue part of the spectrum might have more photons than the red, or it might have less (and it might have more energy than the red, or it might have less); that depends on the source and there's no way to tell without characterizing the source.